# Referring to local settings in a shared form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In .NET 4 winforms I have a solution with several projects. In two of those projects I want to remember the form settings for each form, so I have each form inheriting from a 'CustomForm' which saves and loads position, size etc a settings class, using the ferived form's name as a reference.

For reference, the `CustomForm` code looks like this:

```vb
Public Class CustomForm : Inherits Form

    Private ReadOnly Property SuidenSettings As My.MySettings
        Get
            Return My.MySettings.Default
        End Get
    End Property


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Restore the window settings from the settings file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub RestoreSettings() Handles MyClass.Load

        Dim state As FormWindowState
        Dim settings As List(Of String) = SuidenSettings.Properties.Cast(Of SettingsProperty).Where(Function(p) p.Name.StartsWith(Me.Name)).Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToList()
        Dim primaryWorkArea As Rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

        ' Make sure each setting exists before accessing or exceptions will fly
        If settings.Any() Then
            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_Location") Then
                Me.Location = CType(SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_Location"), Point)
            End If

            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_Size") Then
                Me.Size = CType(SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_Size"), Size)
            End If

            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_State") Then
                If [Enum].TryParse(SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_State").ToString(), state) Then
                    Me.WindowState = state
                Else
                    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
                End If
            End If
        End If

        ' Verify that the form is actually positioned on screen, otherwise position it on the primary screen
        If Not IsOnScreen() Then
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X Mod primaryWorkArea.Width, Me.Location.Y Mod primaryWorkArea.Height)
            If Not primaryWorkArea.Contains(New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size)) Then
                Me.Location = New Point(primaryWorkArea.Top, primaryWorkArea.Left)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Save the form settings to the settings file
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overridable Sub SaveSettings() Handles MyClass.FormClosed

        Dim settings As List(Of String) = SuidenSettings.Properties.Cast(Of SettingsProperty).Where(Function(p) p.Name.StartsWith(Me.Name)).Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToList()

        ' Make sure each setting exists before accessing or exceptions will fly
        If settings.Any() Then
            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_Location") Then
                SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_Location") = Me.Location
            End If

            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_Size") Then
                SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_Size") = Me.Size
            End If

            If settings.Contains(Me.Name & "_State") Then
                SuidenSettings(Me.Name & "_State") = Me.WindowState
            End If
            Call SuidenSettings.Save()
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Check if the form is at least partially visible on screen
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>True if the form is partially visible on screen, else false</returns>
    Private Function IsOnScreen() As Boolean

        Dim formRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size)

        Return Screen.AllScreens.Any(Function(s) s.WorkingArea.IntersectsWith(formRectangle))

    End Function

End Class
```

I used this approach when I still had a single project and it worked fine. Now, I have had to duplicate that project to run two (slightly different programs side by side - please don't ask why I had to do that, I just had to). So I have taken out the `CustomForm` object and put it in a separate project which I reference in both of the application projects.

The problem I have now is that I don't know how I have to modify the `CustomForm` code so that it will reference a settings file which is local to the project in which the form is being used, rather than a settings file in the Shared project.

Since the form settings are retrieved using the form name and both projects are virtually identical, all forms have the same name. I'd like to avoid having to rename all the forms in my projects to slightly different names and instead load the settings from a settings file local to the project. Is that possible?

Any answer in C# or VB.NET would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor the code to also use the application executable path.

For example:

```
If settings.Contains(Application.ExecutablePath & "_" & Me.Name & "_Location") Then
    SuidenSettings(Application.ExecutablePath & "_" & Me.Name & "_Location") = Me.Location
End If
```

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried this in a new solution and don't think it works because the `ExecutablePath` for the application is the same no matter which project you reference it in.

Answer (score 0):

Derek Thomas's answer put me on teh right track. I think I can use `Me.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name` in the `CustomForm` class which returns the name of the assembly in which the instance lives. And then I can rework my settings to include the assembly + form name.

It's not quite what I asked for but it does the trick I guess.